# Mutt: reply in thread and add message from another conversation

Tags: mutt

I’m using mutt.

There are two different e-mail threads (A and B) and I’d like to forward a single message from thread B to thread A.

I could enter thread B and forward said message to the correspondents of A, but that would start a new thread C.

How can I reply within conversation A and attach the message from B, so the thread stays intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach a message to an email the same way you attach a file.

When your finish editing your message and get the view showing headers and attachments, press `A` (uppercase A). This will prompt for a mailbox. Tag all the messages you want to attach and then press `q` to exit back to the attachments view.

Comment: I attach stuff using a all the time but never used A. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Get the Message-ID of the message in thread A that you want to reference in the forwarded message (either the first message in the thread or some later message).

When forwarding the message, add an "In-Reply-To: " header with the appropriate Message-ID.

When you send the forwarding message, it will appear to be a reply to `<Message-ID>`.

You will need to have `set edit_headers` in your ~/.muttrc to do this.  From `man muttrc`:

> edit_headers
>
> ```
> Type: boolean
>
> Default: no
>
> This option allows you to edit the header of your outgoing messages 
> along with the body of your message.
>
> Although the compose menu may have localized header labels, the
> labels passed to your editor will be standard RFC 2822 headers, (e.g. 
> To:, Cc:, Subject:).  Headers added in your editor must also be RFC 2822
> headers, or one of the pseudo headers listed in “edit-header”.  Mutt
> will not understand localized header labels, just as it would not when
> parsing an actual email.
>
> Note that changes made to the References: and Date: headers are ignored
> for interoperability reasons.
> ```

As usual when forwarding a message in mutt, you can edit the message body as required, like adding your own comments or an explanation of why you forwarded it.

You will probably want to clean up any excess quoted text, .signature lines, and other junk from the forwarded message before sending it.  Or not...some mailing lists are tolerant of stuff like that, and others hate it.

Finally, be aware of the original sender's privacy (and their copyright).  Do you have their permission to forward their message outside of the context they sent it?  If not, then ask for it.  Will you be exposing them to harassment or ridicule or other harmful consequences?   Think very carefully about the consequences before sending.